# ClearSheet function not working on all tabs of spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet that needs certain cells to be cleared at midnight every night. It has 3 tabs titled '`DOV`', '`EMD`', and '`Taylor's sheet`', and on each of these sheets the same range needs cleared (D6:D100).

I used '`Taylor's sheet`' as a test sheet because I haven't coded in forever and wanted to to make sure everything worked well first. So I implemented the `clearContent()` for the designated range and everything came out fine. However, once I tried adding the '`DOV`' and '`EMD`' sheets like my original test sheet I keep getting errors regarding the `getRange` function.

```
function ClearSheet1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Taylor's Sheet");
  sheet.getRange("D6:D100").clearContent();  

  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("EMD");
  sheet1.getRange("D6:D100").clearContent();

  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("DOV");
  sheet2.getRange("D6:D100").clearContent();  
}
```

I'm confused why using `getRange` is returning an error

> "Cannot call method 'getRange' of null."

Do I need to break each of these out into its own function?

Comment: If you get that error, then sheet you tried to access doesn't exist in the workbook you are using.

Comment: Also note that you don't need to reacquire the active spreadsheet each time - you have it already as `ss`. Consider also refactoring your code to work for an arbitrary number of sheets by placing the desired names in an array, and iterating it. This is sensible because, as you say, you want to do the same thing on each of them.